# while charging one time on stripe laravel facing error

Tags: laravel, stripe-payments, laravel-cashier

i am using cashier 10 and stripe 7 and i am creating monthly, yearly and life time subscription.
Montlhy and Yealry subscription is working fine but life time charge generate error

```
The provided PaymentMethod is already attached to another object. You cannot reuse PaymentMethods without attaching them to a Customer object first.
```

in controller

```
$user->charge((int)$request->plan_price*100, $request->paymentMethod);
```

Comment: The error tells you what is wrong. Without having read the documentation, my guess is that you are not allowed to use a card(Or some other payment method) more than once, unless it is connected to a customer/user/account. Search for this error and read through the documentation, the answer is in there for sure.

Comment: Hi Irshad, payment methods in Stripe are singe-use unless you save them to a Stripe Customer first. In this case, what might have happened is that you tried to make a charge with a payment method that was used already but hadn't been saved to a Customer. I would recommend following this guide here which will walk you through the process of making reusable payment methods: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/billing#storing-payment-methods

Comment: thanks this solved my problem